# My image is not showing on php but it is when i preview it on a html file

Tags: php, html

So when i view my codeon a html file without the php code inside it and just the html the images show up but then when i upload my php file to the server and go to my website everything shows up except the images.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
     <img src="images/forexample.jpg" class="slideshow-images">
     <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

what could be the problem here, because clearly my images show up when i runt he html but thne when i upload it to the server as a php with all my php codes inside as well it doesn't work, and yes I seperate the php correctly:

```
<?php
  php code in here
?>

html things right below it
```

and that would be my file with the exact html that i run on my computer whcih all the image show up on, in the html things area that i showed above, what could be wrong, and yes I have my folders set exactly the same on the server as on my computer files for my site.

I also have @media screens on my css but that shouldn't be the problem, i think.... also like i said they are both the same html since i test it out on my computer first and then copy the html into the php file html area and have it linked to my css aswell obvs.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your post with your PHP please ? Also can you try to change the src by : './images/forexample.jpg'

Comment: @RomainV Omg i just realised something after i was looking to copy my php, I also made a script for it to work because i made an image slider.... and i forgot to add the script to my server...but thanks you made me realise :D